# how to add online created android theme in my project

Tags: android, themes, manifest

I am new to android application development.I used http://android-holo-colors.com/
to create theme for my application.

It created a theme named ei_theme.
I got the drawable folders,layout,and values folder.
The values folder consist of colors_ei_theme,dimens_ei_theme,styles_ei_theme,themes_ei_theme.

Now i am confused what to add in the manifest file to use the theme.
I guess u cant add more than one theme to in application tag in the manifest.
Can u please tell me how to use these.

here are the contents of styles_ei_theme

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

 <!-- Generated with http://android-holo-colors.com -->

 -<resources xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">


 -<style parent="android:Widget.Holo.AutoCompleteTextView" name="AutoCompleteTextViewEi_Theme">

 <item name="android:dropDownSelector">@drawable/ei_theme_list_selector_holo_dark</item>

 <item name="android:background">@drawable/ei_theme_edit_text_holo_dark</item>

 </style>


 -<style parent="android:Widget.Holo.Button" name="ButtonEi_Theme">

 <item name="android:background">@drawable/ei_theme_btn_default_holo_dark</item>

 </style>


 -<style parent="android:Widget.Holo.ImageButton" name="ImageButtonEi_Theme">

 <item name="android:background">@drawable/ei_theme_btn_default_holo_dark</item>

 </style>


 -<style name="TabEi_Theme">

 <item name="android:gravity">center_horizontal</item>

 <item name="android:paddingLeft">16dip</item>

 <item name="android:paddingRight">16dip</item>

 <item name="android:background">@drawable/ei_theme_tab_indicator_holo</item>

 <item name="android:layout_width">0dip</item>

 <item name="android:layout_weight">1</item>

 <item name="android:minWidth">80dip</item>

 </style>


 -<style name="TabTextEi_Theme">

 <item name="android:textColor">#ffffff</item>

 <item name="android:textSize">12sp</item>

 <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>

 <!-- v14 <item name="android:textAllCaps">true</item> -->


 <item name="android:ellipsize">marquee</item>

 <item name="android:maxLines">2</item>

 <item name="android:maxWidth">180dip</item>

 </style>

 </resources>
```

here are contents of themes_ei_theme

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

  <!-- Generated with http://android-holo-colors.com -->

  -<resources xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">


  -<style parent="android:Theme.Holo" name="Ei_Theme">

  <item name="android:editTextBackground">@drawable/ei_theme_edit_text_holo_dark</item>

  <item name="android:textColorHighlight">#9933b5e5</item>

  <item name="android:textSelectHandleLeft">@drawable/ei_theme_text_select_handle_left</item>

  <item name="android:textSelectHandleRight">@drawable/ei_theme_text_select_handle_right</item>

  <item name="android:textSelectHandle">@drawable/ei_theme_text_select_handle_middle</item>

  <item name="android:autoCompleteTextViewStyle">@style/AutoCompleteTextViewEi_Theme</item>

  <item name="android:listChoiceIndicatorMultiple">@drawable/ei_theme_btn_check_holo_dark</item>

  <item name="android:listChoiceIndicatorSingle">@drawable/ei_theme_btn_radio_holo_dark</item>

  <item name="android:buttonStyle">@style/ButtonEi_Theme</item>

  <item name="android:imageButtonStyle">@style/ImageButtonEi_Theme</item>

  </style>

  </resources>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two ways to apply theme to your activity through **AndroidManifest.xml** file.

**1-** Apply theme in the **application** tag. This applies this theme to all activities in the application like:

```
<application
android:theme = "@style/Ei_Theme" >
...
</application>
```

**2-** Apply theme to each activity individually in **AndroidManifest.xml** under **application** tag. This applies this theme to only this activity:

```
<application >
    <activity
     android:theme = "@style/Ei_Theme" >
     ...
    </activity>
</application>
```

Comment: Your code says
android:theme = "@style/Ei_Theme" >

but Ei_theme is in themes_ei_theme folder.

Comment: plus i want to add theme for every checkbox,radio,dropdown etc...
which are specified in styles_ei_theme.

they are all under different theme names how to add all of them?

Comment: You need to use Ei_Theme. This theme contains all other themes customization in it

Comment: One more thing..if Ei_Theme contains all customizations and it is specified in themes_ei_theme.....then what exactly is contained in styles_ei_theme?
what does this file convey?

Comment: you can write your own themes in Theme file or style file. your choice